# How to dynamically change the text size in Android

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I want to implement a function,

EditText user when entering text, you can make changes in accordance with the set font size,

Such as Google Docs of Office,

[image]

Now I found a way to `SpannableString`, but read some examples seem unable to reach my needs

```
int index = input.getSelectionEnd();
SpannableString  spann = new SpannableString(show_input);
AbsoluteSizeSpan word_size = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(18,true);
spann.setSpan(word_size, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
input.getText().insert(index, spann);
```

So is there any way to provide it?

Comment: your question is not understandable please provide what you want and what you have. also add some code

Comment: Its complicated. But SpannableString will work for you. You just need to do some brain storming.

Comment: spann.setSpan(word_size, startStringPosition, endStringPosition, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want to change size of selected text:

```
int start = editText.getSelectionStart();
int end = editText.getSelectionEnd();
Spannable text=(Spannable)editText.getText();
text.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(NEW_TEXT_SIZE, true), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editText.setText(text);
```

Use [AbsoluteSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.html) to change for actual size or [RelativeSizeSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html)  for proportional size.

Answer (score 0):

I trird to add TextWatcher(),

```
input =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Input_EditText); 
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        int index = input.getSelectionEnd();
        String nowstr;

        if(index==0)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            nowstr = s.toString();
            char nowstr_array[] = nowstr.toCharArray();
            show_input = String.valueOf(nowstr_array[index-1]);

            SpannableStringBuilder  spann = new SpannableStringBuilder(show_input);
            AbsoluteSizeSpan word_size = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(40,true);
            spann.setSpan(word_size, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            input.getText().insert(index, spann);
        }
    }
});
```

But this program will crash...

then,I try to do

```
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, spann, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //input.getText().insert(index, spann);
```

But doing so can be displayed...

That is why?

Comment: What line it crashed? Add crashlog.